# How can I pass service function in Angular2 route

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular4-router

how to concate "TTENCommonService.getRole()" in path?
In getRole() event i have return the string value.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { TTENCommonService } from './tten-common/services/tten- 
  common.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard '+ TTENCommonService.getRole(), pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is outside the class. You can call new operator on it. Please see the below code.

Hope it helps.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard '+ new TTENCommonService().getRole(), pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```